# asp.net 4.0 dynamic data GridviewPager specifying number of pages

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pagination, paging, dynamic-data

I am currently using  Dynamic Data Linq to SQL for a project. I was wondering if there is a way to change the available options for the number of items to display on a page for the GridView. Currently the "Results Per Page:" drop down list only gives me options for 5, 10, 15 and 20. I want to add 50 and 100 options to display 50 or 100 items per page.

The GridView control is using the GridViewPager control to generate the paging controls/dropdown list. I can set the PageSize property on the GridView to 50 for example and have 50 items showing per page, but how do I change the GridViewPager to let the user pick the additional options of 50 or 100?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I figured it out. There is a file in DynamicData\Content called GridViewPager.ascx that actually controls the paging. You'll see in the source that there is a dropdownlist and that you can add additional listitem values.